# How to use aiohttp with ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, asynchronous, threadpool, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I now have this code:

```
def parse_url(i):
    url = f"https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-{i}/"
    print(f"Started {str(i)}")
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(f"Ended {str(i)}")
    return r.content


async def get_urls(executor):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [
        loop.run_in_executor(executor, parse_url, i)
        for i in range(8001, 8033)
    ]
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
    s = time.perf_counter()
    loop.run_until_complete(
        get_urls(executor)
    )
    loop.close()
```

Now the work is splitted between 2 threads, but each thread is doing request sequentially, what I want is standard async behaviour on each thread with aiohttp:

1. Start a request
2. While waiting for data open another request
3. Receive result of request

loop.run_in_executor does not allow coroutines to be passed as parameter, how can I achieve my desire?

Comment: instead of using requests.get you could use aiohttp.ClientSession - which would be async.  See https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#make-a-request

Comment: @Richard to use aiohttp.ClientSession async function is requeired (coroutine), but courotine cannot be passed to run_in_executor method

Comment: `run_in_executor` is for cpu-bound or legacy sync code. Why do you want to pass it a coroutine? If you want your coroutine to run in the "background", call `asyncio.create_task`.